# Spring: How to pass value to nested Bean constructor during runtime

Tags: java, spring

Consider these two classes.

```
@Component
public class Foo {
    private String name;

    public Foo(@Value("name") String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Component
public class Bar {
    private Foo foo;

    public Bar(@Value("#{bar}") Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo
    }
}
```

How do I change the value of name in Foo, before passing it to Bar?

Without Spring, we can do this

```
Foo foo = new Foo("newName");
Bar bar = new bar(foo);
// do something with bar
```

But how I do this with Spring at runtime?

---

Runtime will be something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "newValue"; // get from user or read from a file
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("foo.xml");
    // do some magic here
    Bar bar = context.getBean("bar", Bar.class);
    assert bar.getFoo().getName().equals(name);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use spring for everything...

Comment: how do you mean exactly "at Runtime"? if you use DI (like @Automwired) for the Foo field, I would suggest to use a qualifier (like @Qualifier) or @Resource, where you can specify a bean ID. Besides this you should also instantiate a Bean with this ID and set its name value as you like.

You can achieve this with xml configuraitons as well, where you can name beans with IDs, set their properties as you wish, and you can reference them in other beans as "ref".

Comment: If I understand your question @Value("${some.property}") does the job where *some.property* is a property stored somewhere e.g. in a properties file (application.properties, application-<profile>.properties)